# An excellent 2.5 months for the review queues, let's continue alternatives to close voting!

Tags: discussion, culture, policies, close-reasons, vote-to-close

**In February we had 6** questions in the close vote queue that we ultimately decided to keep open.
**In March we had 4**.
**In April we had 1**.
**In May we had 0**.

***Since 26 march we've had only 1***.

In fact for more than 2.5 months, close vote reviewers (who are unpaid volunteers by the way) have not been asked at all to review any questions for closure.

**Let's continue this trend of alternatives to close voting, such as: *leaving constructive comments and **allowing the OP time** to make improvements*.**

The benefits of having a welcoming community in which users do not feel discouraged to ask questions due to seeing close votes on questions before they've had a chance to be told what was actually wrong in the comments, and to actually respond with improvements to the question, are in my opinion great.

- For [abandoned questions](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/162/5), feel free to flag for a moderator to hammer close, as we've been doing now for months.
- For very-low-quality questions, continue to flag the question and select the VLQ option!
- For *spam* and CoC violations, please flag them as such!
- For duplicate questions, leave a comment [like I did here (you'll only be able to see it if you have enough rep to see deleted questions though](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4747/determining-if-an-organic-material-may-be-a-superconductor-from-first-principles#comment9480_4747) and the user may voluntarily delete the question themselves (as they did in this case), which saves them the "embarrassment" of having to have their question enter the close-vote queue.

If a user is not responding to comments for a couple weeks, then feel free to close vote afterwards!